# webpack not found in package.json for asp.net core 2.1 with Angular project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In VS 2017 15.8.3 I create an ASP.net Core 2.1 with Angular. I do not see webpack in package.json and no webpack.config.js. but I do see this in ASP.net Core 2 with angular.

Is this on purpose? do i have to configure webpack for asp.net core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

which version of angular it is ?

if it is angular 5 then `webpack` will create on fly and angular 5 is complete cli support.

go through it for more info [link](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-5-app-with-visual-studio-2017/)

Comment: I thought angular version(template) is based on `aspnetcore` versions(?)